# The model shown not updating when returning a PartialView with a new/updated model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I wish to update the values of my model with a button and get back to the same partial view.

I am on a page called "Edit" and want to alter some of the values of a model in the controller and then send the user to the PartialView("Edit",modelWithNewValues)(the page I am already on).
The page shows the new values if I call them with @Model.Id but my @Html.TextBox("Id", Model.Id, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" }) is showing the old values.

What do I need to do to show the updated values?

Comment: Please include your controller and view codes.

Answer (score 1):

ModelState.Clear(); Made it possible

Ofcourse I manage minutes after I post it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).